# Mongodb, filter nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and need some help with building a query.
I have a collection of documents like this:

```
{
  "userId": "AAAA",
  "settings": [
    {
      "key": "theme",
      "value": "Dark"
    },
    {
      "key": "btnColor",
      "value": "blue"
    },
    {
      "key": "otherSetting",
      "value": "otherValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have an array of keys (passing to the server), like **[theme, btnColor, someNonExistingKey]**
And I need to get a document by userId with settings which keys are inside the array of keys, so I need to get that:

```
{
  "userId": "AAAA",
  "settings": [
    {
      "key": "theme",
      "value": "Dark"
    },
    {
      "key": "btnColor",
      "value": "blue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone please help me with correct query?

Answer (score 1):

1. `$match` - Filter the document by `userId` and `settings.key` in provided input array.
2. `$project` - Decorate output documents. For `settings` field, filter the document by `key` is existed in provided input array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: "AAAA",
      "settings.key": {
        $in: [
          "theme",
          "btnColor",
          "abc"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "userId": 1,
      "settings": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$settings",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this.key",
              [
                "theme",
                "btnColor",
                "abc"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fImBp89g1j1)